# VBScript to extract "Date Taken" from a photo

Tags: exif, properties

I was wondering if the "Date Taken" property of an image file can be extracted using VBScript?
I know other properties such as date created, modified, accessed can be accessed and already have a working script for the same but can the date taken property be accessed? Because it comes under EXIF data I believe.

I found some old codes, unfortunately, none of them work.

If anyone has any idea I would be greatful.

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GPlP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://paulgrant.ca/code_image_details_gps.html

Trivial modifications to this script can result in the outputting of any EXIF data.

```
'PAULGRANT.CA 2011

Option Explicit
'On Error Resume Next

Const   ForWriting          = 2
Const   FileCreate          = True
Const   TristateTrue        = -1    'Unicode
Const   SecondsToWait       = 10
Const   YesNo               = 4
Const   IconQuestion        = 32

Dim WshShell, iCode, sCurrentFolderName, sOutputFileName
Dim oFS, oFolder, oTS, oImg, oFile
Dim iPos, sExt, sString

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
iCode = WshShell.Popup("Continue?", SecondsToWait, "Run This Script?", YesNo + IconQuestion)
If (iCode <> 6) Then
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

sCurrentFolderName      = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
sOutputFileName         = sCurrentFolderName & "\output.txt"

Set oFS         = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder     = oFS.GetFolder(sCurrentFolderName)
Set oTS         = oFS.OpenTextFile(sOutputFileName, ForWriting, FileCreate, TristateTrue)
Set oImg        = WScript.CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

    iPos    = InStrRev(oFile.Name, ".")
    sExt    = Mid(oFile.Name, iPos)

    If (LCase(sExt) = ".jpg") Then

        sString = DoImage(oFile.Name)
WScript.Echo sString
        If (sString <> "") Then
            oTS.WriteLine sString
        End If

    End If

Next

oTS.Close

WScript.Echo "Done"

'FUNCTIONS

Function DoImage(sFileName)

    Dim i, j, v, s, sOutput, sPropertyName

    sOutput = ""

    oImg.LoadFile sFileName

   'This handles no attribs added by cybernard
    if oImg.Properties.count=0 then
   ' Do something about it
   wscript.echo "File:"&sFileName&" has no attributes"
    End if
   'End of cybernard add
    For i = 1 to oImg.Properties.Count

        sPropertyName = oImg.Properties(i).Name
        WScript.Echo "Prop:"&sPropertyName&"     "&oImg.Properties(i).Value
        If InStr(sPropertyName, "Gps") > 0 Then

            s = sPropertyName & "(" & oImg.Properties(i).PropertyID & ") = "

            If oImg.Properties(i).IsVector Then

                s = s & "[vector]"

                Set v = oImg.Properties(i).Value

                If sPropertyName = "GpsLatitude" Then

                    s = s & FormatCoords(v, oImg.Properties("GpsLatitudeRef").Value)

                ElseIf sPropertyName = "GpsLongitude" Then

                    s = s & FormatCoords(v, oImg.Properties("GpsLongitudeRef").Value)

                Else

                    For j = 1 To v.Count
                        s = s & v(j) & " "
                    Next

                End If

            Else
                s = s & oImg.Properties(i).Value
            End If

            sOutput = sOutput & s & vbCrLf

        End If

    Next

    DoImage = sOutput

End Function

Function FormatCoords(v,sRef)

    'On Error Resume Next

    Dim sCoords

    sCoords = v(1) & Chr(176) & v(2) & Chr(39) & v(3) & Chr(34) & sRef

    FormatCoords = sCoords

End Function

'End.
```

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful! I was able to edit the script a little bit to get just the "Date Taken" attribute.

However, I hate the fact that if there is an image in the folder which does not have any information in that attribute, that image will simply be ignore and the script will move on to the next one.

Comment: @user5793353  What should it do when it encounters an image with either no attributes or no "Date Taken"?  I have added code, but only you can determine what the code should do when it encounters no attribs.